# Concatenate 2 numeric type values to a fixed size number

Tags: math, number

You have 2 numbers, both stored separate as **numeric data type**.

First number is always 6 digits long.

Second number can vary between 1 and 4 digits. If it's less than 4 digits, it needs to be padded with numeric value 0.

End result always needs to be 10 digits number.

Order has to be respected. n1|n2

**Example #1:**

```
n1 = 111111
n2 = 2222
result = 1111112222
```

**Example #2:**

```
n1 = 333333
n2 = 44
result = 3333330044
```

The **rule** is that you can only use **numeric data types** (number, int, float, decimal) to get the desired result.

Comment: _you can only use numeric data types_ That's close to being an [unobservable requirement](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10002/36398). What if a function I call uses strings internally? Also, this needs a winning criterion. Code golf?

Comment: I have a function that converts my number to a string to process it. Am I allowed to use it?

Comment: This one seems really interesting. The only problem is that not every language can guarantee the type at every point of a variable's use. Need to maybe loosen that up a bit (or even restrict to languages that don't require any conversions, internally or otherwise).

Answer (score 3):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 3 bytes

```
♫*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjPz0n7///RzNVa2v//G4KBghEQAAA)

#### Explanation:

```
      Implicit input
 ♫*   Multiply first argument by 10000
   +  Add the two arguments
      Implicit output
```

Comment: Every time i think "This seems like a good challenge for MathGolf", I find you in the answers. Nice answer, goes really well with my idea of having lots of numerical constants to aid in golfing.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 5 bytes

```
1e4*+
```

Uses only addition and multiplication.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/3zDVREv7/39jMOAyMQEA)

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 4 bytes

```
4°*+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f/f5NAGLe3//43BgMvEBAA)

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 14 bytes

```
->a,b{a*1e4+b}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 45 bytes

```
,.,.,.,.,.,.,[-->+++>+++>+++<<<],[<,]>>>>[.<]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKzMxLK03O/v9fRw8JRuvq2mlra8OwjY1NrE60jU6sHRBE69nE/v9vDAYKJgA)

Assumes the inputted numbers are separated by a single space